# How can I check actual column datatype in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

I would like to check actual datatype of all columns in a database and compare the result with the table information_schema.columns. The aim is to detect oversized column data-type to reduce it.

For example if a column is defined as `varchar(255)` but all values as only 10 characters or less I would like to see it in the result.

I know that this query is to get the info on each column :

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'dbo'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Is anybody knows how can I calculate the maximum value for any data-type and compare it to the setting?

Example sample :

```
| ColA (varchar255)| ColB (nvarchar255) |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First    | first row            |
| Second   | row 2            |
| Third    | a row            |
```

Expected result :

```
| Col | type len | actual max len |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| ColA    | 255            | 6 |
| ColB   | 255            | 9 |
```

Comment: Please show some samples and the expected result

Comment: The **actual** data type is a `varchar(255)` though. I don't follow what you're asking

Comment: Is your question how to get the actual maximum number of characters in each varchar/nvarchar column from the underlying tables, and then check that against the defined max length?

Comment: `actual max len` for `ColA` should be `6`

Comment: Once you have this information, what is the real problem you are trying to solve? Are you running out of disk space on your server? How many tables are in the database? Will it cost more money to have a developer change all the field sizes and the code of the applications that use it, vs. just buying more server disk space?

Comment: The aim is to optimize all the DB (CPU, RAM, disk, ...). In that case it's only for disk space (the order of magnitude is in To). It will not cost a single second of a dev time since we have an interface between tha apps and the DB (we do not use EF for that reson). Buying more disk is a simple idea and a quick easy fix but we will have to face the problem again when the disk will be full... It's better optimizing query than buying more CPU, so that's the same idea here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script below executes a MAX DATALENGTH query against each variable-length column to determine the actual max size (in bytes) and lists the results along with the defined max size. This version uses the SQL Server system catalog views instead of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

Be aware this can take some time if your database is large and impact performance. If you run this against an active database without RCSI, consider `READ_UNCOMMITTED` with the understanding the results may not be as accurate.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @results TABLE(
     SchemaName sysname NOT NULL
    ,TableName sysname NOT NULL
    ,ColumnName sysname NOT NULL
    ,DefinedMaxLength int NOT NULL
    ,ActualMaxLength int NULL
);

DECLARE
     @SchemaName sysname
    ,@TableName sysname
    ,@ColumnName sysname
    ,@DefinedMaxLength int
    ,@ActualMaxLength int
    ,@MaxLengthQuery nvarchar(MAX);

DECLARE MaxColumnSizes CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT 
          OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id) AS SchemaName
         ,OBJECT_NAME(t.object_id) AS TableName
         ,c.name AS ColumnName
         ,CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 2147483647 ELSE c.max_length END AS DefinedMaxMength
         ,N'SELECT @ActualMaxLength = MAX(DATALENGTH(' + c.name + N'))'
         + N' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.object_id)) AS MaxLengthQuery
    FROM sys.tables AS t
    JOIN sys.columns AS c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    JOIN sys.types AS ty ON ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id AND ty.system_type_id = c.user_type_id
    WHERE 
        ty.name IN(N'varchar', 'nvarchar', N'varbinary')
        AND OBJECTPROPERTY(t.object_id, 'IsMSShipped') = 0;

OPEN MaxColumnSizes;
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM MaxColumnSizes INTO
         @SchemaName
        ,@TableName
        ,@ColumnName
        ,@DefinedMaxLength
        ,@MaxLengthQuery;
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS = -1 BREAK;
    --PRINT @MaxLengthQuery; --for debugging

    SET @ActualMaxLength = NULL;
    EXEC sp_executesql @MaxLengthQuery, N'@ActualMaxLength int OUTPUT', @ActualMaxLength = @ActualMaxLength OUTPUT;
    INSERT INTO @results (SchemaName, TableName, ColumnName, DefinedMaxLength, ActualMaxLength) 
        VALUES(@SchemaName, @TableName, @ColumnName, @DefinedMaxLength, @ActualMaxLength);
    
END;
CLOSE MaxColumnSizes;
DEALLOCATE MaxColumnSizes;

SELECT 
     SchemaName
    ,TableName
    ,ColumnName
    ,DefinedMaxLength
    ,ActualMaxLength
FROM @results
ORDER BY
     SchemaName
    ,TableName
    ,ColumnName;
GO
```